# While calling service with byte[] its giving 400 bad request

Tags: c#, json, web-services, serialization

I am trying to call services with byte[] but i am getting

> 400: Bad request.

I use below code.

=============================

## Class Structure

```
class DLDShipmentDeliveryStatusResponse
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public ValidationErrors ValidationErrors { get; set; }

}
class ValidationErrors
{
    public int ErrorNumber { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessageAr { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionObject { get; set; }
    public int ValidationType { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
class DLDServiceRequest
{
    public string AWB { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryStatus  { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateTime  { get; set; }
    public List<DLDShipmentDeliveryDocument> ProofOfDeliveryDocumentList { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
class DLDShipmentDeliveryDocument
{
    public byte[] DocumentStream  { get; set; }
    public string DocumentExtension  { get; set; }
}
```

=======

## Calling Service

```
var shipmentDeliveryInfo = new DLDServiceRequest
{
    AWB = "1233455",
    DeliveryStatus = 1,
    LastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now
};

var deliveryDoc = new DLDShipmentDeliveryDocument
{
    DocumentStream = item.ProofOfDelivery,//Here assign value of byte[]
    DocumentExtension = "png"
};
shipmentDeliveryInfo.ProofOfDeliveryDocumentList = new List<DLDShipmentDeliveryDocument>();
shipmentDeliveryInfo.ProofOfDeliveryDocumentList.Add(deliveryDoc);

HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http:....");

httpWReq.Method = Constants.POST;
httpWReq.KeepAlive = false;
httpWReq.ContentType = Constants.JSONContentType;
httpWReq.Headers.Add("X-ApiKey", "-----");
httpWReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;                                               

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(httpWReq.GetRequestStream());
var shipmentJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(shipmentDeliveryInfo);

writer.Write(shipmentJSON);
writer.Close();

json = String.Empty;
using (var response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse())
{
    using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        json = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
var DLDServiceDeptObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DLDShipmentDeliveryStatusResponse>(json);
```

Here i am not mention Host and API key value.

Comment: convert the byte array to base64 string then send it from client and receive it as string in service side.

Comment: i cant send as a string. Bcz class of request parameter have byte[] entity.

Comment: Do you have an example of a good request to this service? Can you make test calls through a tool like PostMan?

Comment: @JeetBhatt Yes yo can't until you change it to string. Change it to string type then try

Comment: @Crowcoder yes itry with telerik fiddler. but same issue. and i dont have any example.

Comment: How did you try with Fiddler if you don't have an example?

Comment: now i try to access service through fiddler.

Comment: Unless you have control of the service you must conform to its API, it will not conform to your classes. You must know what it requires as far as data format. Based on experience you probably need to send that as base64 so you probably have some work to do on your classes or the serialization of them.